# How could I write multiple "compareTo" methods in just one class?

Tags: java, comparator

I'm comparing and sorting multiple attribute by two objects, but for that I created different classes to compare those different attributes.

This is in my main class:

```
Collections.sort(Comparator, new SortByRef());
        System.out.println("\nOrdenado por Referencia");
        for(int i=0; i<Comparator.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(Comparator.get(i));


        Collections.sort(Comparator, new SortByMonto());
        System.out.println("\nOrdenado por Monto");
        for(int i=0; i<Comparator.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(Comparator.get(i));

        Collections.sort(Comparator, new SortByDes());
        System.out.println("\nOrdenado por Descripcion");
        for(int i=0; i<Comparator.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(Comparator.get(i));

        Collections.sort(Comparator, new SortByNP());
        System.out.println("\nOrdenado por Numero de parte");
        for(int i=0; i<Comparator.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(Comparator.get(i));
```

As you can see, in `Collections.sort`, I created different `SortBy...`, I mean, different classes for each one.

But I want to create just ONE class to compare all the attributes. How could I do it?

For example, these are my methods I created:

```
public int compare(COSTOS ref1, COSTOS ref2) {
        return ref1.referencia - ref2.referencia;}

public int compare(COSTOS monto1, COSTOS monto2) {
        return (int) (monto1.monto - monto2.monto);
    }
```

Comment: Why? What's your actual goal?

Comment: Usually you define `compareTo()` method in your class which will be used in most cases to sort collections of objects. And then you create separate `Comparator` classes if you need different sort order in some places.

Comment: so, it would be unnecessary ?  it's ok by the way i'm doing it? my main goal about this was to use less classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating multiple classes that implement the `Comparator` interface, you can just create multiple methods that do the comparison. Then, the method itself basically **is** (!) the implementation of the `Comparator`, and you can just pass it to the `Collections#sort` method, using a method reference.

Depending on how the comparison will actually take place, an even more concise form would be to use the [`Comparator#comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) methods, as [Donat mentioned in his answer (+1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53092678/3182664). Specifically, you could use `comparingInt` in your example. Both approaches are shown here:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class MultipleCompareMethods
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Costos> list = new ArrayList<Costos>();

        list.add(new Costos(1,3));
        list.add(new Costos(4,5));
        list.add(new Costos(2,7));

        // Using Method references

        Collections.sort(list, MultipleCompareMethods::compareByReferencia);
        System.out.println("\nOrdenado por Referencia");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(list.get(i));

        Collections.sort(list, MultipleCompareMethods::compareByMonto);
        System.out.println("\nOrdenado por Monto");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(list.get(i));


        // Using Comparator#comparingInt:

        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(c -> c.referencia));
        System.out.println("\nOrdenado por Referencia");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(list.get(i));

        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(c -> c.monto));
        System.out.println("\nOrdenado por Monto");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(list.get(i));

    }

    static int compareByReferencia(Costos c0, Costos c1)
    {
        return Integer.compare(c0.referencia, c1.referencia);
    }
    static int compareByMonto(Costos c0, Costos c1)
    {
        return Integer.compare(c0.monto, c1.monto);
    }

}


class Costos
{
    int referencia;
    int monto;

    Costos(int referencia, int monto)
    {
        this.referencia = referencia;
        this.monto = monto;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "COSTOS [referencia=" + referencia + ", monto=" + monto + "]";
    }
}


class Costos
{
    int referencia;
    int monto;

    Costos(int referencia, int monto)
    {
        this.referencia = referencia;
        this.monto = monto;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "COSTOS [referencia=" + referencia + ", monto=" + monto + "]";
    }
}
```

If you offered methods like `getReferencia` in your class, this could be done even more concisely, again using a method reference:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(Costos::getReferencia));
```

(Since Java 8, it's hardly ever necessary to actually implement own comparator classes...)

Comment: thank you!! this is what i was looking for! just one question... what means ' :: ' ?
located right here: Collections.sort(list, MultipleCompareMethods::compareByMonto);

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html : The meaning of `SomeClass::someMethod` can roughly be imagined as "This is an object that contains **only** a single method - namely, `someMethod`". (In your case, this can be imagined as "the comparator object")

Answer (score 1):

I think, you don't want to make a separate class for each sorting order. But it does not work the way you tried. I think, Comparator is a variable with type List of something. Maybe you should try something like this instead:

```
comparator.sort(comparing(c -> c.referencia));
System.out.println("\nOrdenado por Referencia");
comparator.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The method "comparing" here is a static import from the type Comparator of the Java Class Library. This makes you a new comparator without the need of a new named top-level class.

You should start your variable names (here: Comparator) with lowercase letters. This is a general convention in Java.